# Invisible file with a specific real name - can't list it, delete it or create new file of that name

Tags: symbolic-link, vagrant

I seem to have an 'invisible' folder that I can't see or delete, but is blocking a 'real' file from being created.

I'm in a vagrant box (Ubuntu 14)

I was trying to install https://code.google.com/p/apptrace/ Python package but seemed to hit this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907359/problem-setting-up-a-virtualenv so I altered the init script not to create symlinks (intending it would fallback to copy files via `shutil.copy2` instead)

Anyway, it still failed with Protocol Error... this is not my question though, just background.

Now though I seem to have an 'invisible' `apptrace` file/folder that I can't see or delete, but is blocking a 'real' file from being created:

```
$ sudo ls -la
total 6640
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant    1326 Oct 14 11:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 9 vagrant vagrant    4096 Oct 14 11:46 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant    1722 Oct 14 09:46 appengine_config.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant    1077 Oct 14 09:59 appengine_config.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant     760 Oct 14 09:33 app.yaml
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant     170 Oct  8 10:24 campaigns
```

and:

```
$ file *
appengine_config.py:          Python script, ASCII text executable
appengine_config.pyc:         python 2.7 byte-compiled
app.yaml:                     ASCII text
campaigns:                    directory
```

and:

```
$ rm -rf apptrace
rm: cannot remove ‘apptrace’: Is a directory
$ rm -r apptrace
rm: cannot remove ‘apptrace’: No such file or directory
$ sudo vi apptrace
(says [Permission Denied] at bottom of screen, despite sudo, and can't be saved)
$ cd apptrace
apptrace$ <-- worked
apptrace$ sudo ls -la
ls: cannot open directory .: Operation not permitted
apptrace$ sudo vi newfile
(does NOT say [Permission Denied] but fails E212: Can't open file for writing on save)
```

(all commands above run while sshed into the vagrant box)

Please help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Reading around a bit, such as here: http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2330/04f/notes/links_and_inodes.html it sounded like I might have ended up with an 'orphaned' inode.

Reading a bit more it looked like I needed to run the `fsck` tool to repair the, er, thingamijigs.

You can't run `fsck` on a file system that's mounted, at least not without dire consequences according to `fsck` itself.

However I read that Linux will run `fsck` on startup so it turned out the fix for my problem was to just reboot the vagrant box.

I would love to hear further answers if you know a way to more specifically target the specific orphan without rebooting the server, or if you have any clue about how this orphan got created in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd apptrace
```

_

```
ls -lisa:
--------
4110     24 drwxrwxrwt 20 root  root      12288 Okt 14 17:52 .
   2      8 drwxr-xr-x 22 root  root       4096 Sep 11 13:27 ..
....
```

_

```
cd ..
```

_

```
sudo find . -inum 4110 -delete
```

should delete your orphaned dir / file

Comment: unfortunately `ls` did not work, see details in question